# Flutter available camera returns null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the flutter camera plugin to record a video but the code keeps throwing:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

when I try to get the first camera (`cameras.first` or `cameras[0]`). This is happening even with the examples given in the plugin docs: https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example

Here's my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
# @format

name: camera_example
description: A camera example app

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  archive: ^3.1.2
  bloc: ^7.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  dio: null
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  eva_icons_flutter: ^3.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^7.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  http: ^0.13.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.2
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  line_icons: null
  logger: null
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  video_player: ^2.1.10
  camera:
    # path: ./
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  marquee: ^2.2.0
  responsive_builder: ^0.4.1
  page_indicator: ^0.4.1
  path: ^1.8.0
  permission_handler:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#000000"
  image: "assets/images/bg.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: TikTokIcons
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/TikTokIcons.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I believe I have done everything according to the documentation but I keep on getting the error. I am testing on a real android(android 10) device.
The example code I'm referring to:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: I'm new to flutter

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede I'm using the code exactly as it is in the examples for testing: https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example

Comment: @Hillux sorry, but that can't be right. the example contains: 'List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];' --- ie. it is a non-nullable type. It can never be null.

Comment: Hi @HerbertPoul I've edited the question to add the example question I'm testing with. Kindly have a look